# JAVA interceptor does not work when pass extra headers in http request by JS

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, interceptor

**Dispatcher-servlet.xml file config**

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <bean class="com.redhat.obpa.controller.interceptor.CORSInterceptor">
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <!-- <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/**"/> -->
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/onboarding/login, /proctor/login"/>
        <bean class="com.redhat.obpa.controller.interceptor.AuthInterceptor">

        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

**prehandle interceptor Code**

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                         HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                         Object object) throws Exception {

    String token = httpServletRequest.getHeader(LabelConstant.SCHECULING_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN);

    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, 
            PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, 
                    Content-Type, X-Auth-Token");

    throw new BusinessException(ErrorConstant.EC_152,  ErrorConstant.EC_152_DESC);
}
```

**So when we pass extra header in the request - our custom Exception class does not call and when we pass request without header it calls.**

```
**// IT WORKS**
xhttp.open("POST", "url", true);
xhttp.send();

**// IT FAILES**
xhttp.open("POST", "url", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token", "mytoken");
xhttp.send();
```